# custom field not displaying in visualforce page for user object

Tags: custom-field

In my visualforce page I am displaying two fields from User object.
{!$User.Alias} 
where 'Alias' is a standard field and is displaying fine.
But {!$User.message__c} 
 where 'message__c' is custom object and is not displaying at all. 
Please help me know how can I display {!$User.message__c} in my visualforce page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error? if not, it should be a permission issue. Please check the field level security and field accessibility option for that field.

Comment: How did you create a lookup field on User object? It is not possible to create a custom lookup relationship with other objects than user object iteself on User record. Is it that the Message custom object have loopup to User?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a permissions error. The user's profile settings lack visibility to your custom field, and therefore the associated input field on your VF page refuses to render.

If you grant read and/or edit access (depending on your needs) either from the profile settings or using a permission set, the field should display without issue.